# Integrate Ads in Android Phonegap Build

Tags: android, html, phonegap-build

I am trying to integrate ads in Phonegap build android Application.

Integrating admob is not possible in html5 phonegap build.

I tried with MOBFOX (http://www.mobfox.com/) ad networks.

But ads not showing properly and I am not sure about their reliability compare to admob.

Please kindly suggest me the suitable ad networks for phonegap build android apps.

Answer (score 1):

I have not been able to find any way at all to do this. I ended up having to work with the local CLI version of phonegap and this plugin for AdMob: https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-plugin-admob

Comment: This is currently the only solution to your problem. Pheongap Build is looking into a plugin but it could be awhile! Source: http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/phonegap_build_admob_advert_plugin?utm_source=notification&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=new_comment&utm_content=topic_link

Comment: Is this still the only solution? No way to do it in phonegap build yet?

Answer (score 0):

In this discussion they found other solutions:
http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/how_do_you_incorporate_advertising_or_banner_ads
but it seems to be not really possible to integrate ads in phonegap. 
I look for more.